# How to find irreducible polynomial for Barreto-Naehrig curves?

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, elliptic-curves

As described in this [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/390.pdf)(section 3) to implement pairing on Barreto-Naehrig curves. The prime in their case is $p=82434016654300679721217353503190038836571781811386228921167322412819029493183$ and to implement the pairing it is important to find an irreducible polynomial of the form $ W^6-\xi$ in $\mathbb{F}_{P^{2}}$ where $\xi \in \mathbb{F}_{P^{2}}$. However, I can not understand how to find such $\xi$. I have written some scripts in Magma to find such $\xi$ but not successful.Also in that paper they have mentioned that there are some properties of the prime $p$ which is useful in finding such $\xi$ but I can't understand how to use them? Can someone please tell me how to find such irreducible polynomials?

Comment: Do you know how many sixth roots of unity $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ contains?

Comment: It is $gcd(6,p^2-1)$

Comment: I understand I can calculate sixth roots of unity in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, but how can I use that to create irreducible polynomials of the above form?

Comment: I was hoping for a an actual number rather than for an expression ...

Comment: The number  is 6.